# How to find all unused properties in Entity Framwork model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Model with many tables and columns and i want to clear it, searching for all unused columns.

It's not possible do it one by one searching for their references.

There's a way to do that?

Comment: Resharper will "grey out" unused members. You could also try VS Code Analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) to remove unused stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For properties, No. Let's say you have one `PCOCO` class `Employee` (which is database table) with 15 properties. Now you are using it everywhere in your project. Somewhere you are assigning values to 12  properties and somewhere else 10. Its nearly impossible to determine that which one you are using and not using. For your answer, you have to search for `Employee` class in your project and find the reference of particular class. Then you have to check your self that which one you're not using. For your curiosity, you can check **Resharper** tool which is favorite of .NET developers. You might get something you are looking for!